# How long does it take for an atom's electronic configuration to change?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, atomic-physics

For example, there's an atom and you attach an electron to it. After the atom receives this extra electron, its electronic configuration changes into a new one. How long does the changing process take?

Comment: You can obtain a rough estimate from the time-scale associated with multi-photon excitation physics, or a slightly rougher one just by dividing the size of the atom by the speed of light.

Comment: @dmckee Why do you say 'dividing atom size by light speed'? Are electrons moving at light speed?

Comment: Light speed represents the fastest possible speed of change and the size of the atom represents the longest length scale that might be involved. It's a very rough back-of-an-envelope type number. The real time could be an order of magnitude or two longer or shorter.

Comment: @dmckee That sounds reasonable. But you mentioned photoexcitation in your first comment...I don't think my question has anything to do with excitation. If there's an electron excited to a higher state in the atom, it should take no time, right? I mean, after an electron absorbs a photon, it immediately jumps to a higher orbital - I think the jumping takes no time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend on many factors, but electronic transitions typically fall within the attosecond-femtosecond range (with some exotic behaviour like excitonic states surviving to the picosecond time-scale).

The closest answer to your specific question that I could find was [this study](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature03833) which found electrons to hop between atoms on a time-scale of ~320 attoseconds.